# Symfony 3.1 login errors are not bubbling up with HWIOAuthBundle + FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

The integration of HWIOAuthBundle + FOSUserBundle works fine along with the Facebook and Google sign-in option (Symfony 3.1). If the user enters valid username and password, then no worries, everything is smooth. However when the credentials are incorrect (for the case of FOSUserBundle with local user data), **errors are not bubbling! :(**

The error messages from FOSUserBundle should normally be stored inside `error` variable but when I try  `dump(error)` in twig, there is no value set for this variable. I hope HWIOAuthBundle is not interfering with error variables from FOSUserBundle. Does anyone know how to fix this?

My views are stored as follows:

```
[app]
    [Resources]
        [FOSUserBundle]
            [view]
                [Security]
                    login.html.twig
                    login_content.html.twig

        [HWIOAuthBundle]
            [view]
                [Connect]
                    login.html.twig
```

**Update:** Problem solved

After inspecting the code, I found out that the *controller override of Hwi* that I used had the following block of codes, that was responsible for resetting the `$error` variable to `null`.

```
/**
 * @author Alexander <iam.asm89@gmail.com>
 */
class ConnectController extends Controller {
    public function connectAction(Request $request) {

        ....            
        /* FOLLOWING BLOCK WAS CREATING PROBLEM */
        /*
        if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
            $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
            $session->remove($authErrorKey);
        } else {
            $error = null;
        }
        */

        ....

    }

    ...

}
```

After removal of this block, the error bubbling was restored.